# How can I replace a imaginary number with nan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, sympy, complex-numbers

I have calculated values with Sympy. Some of them are complex, but I don't want them. Before I'm writing them in a list, I want to replace the imaginary numbers with a nan.

I tried various kind of code like:

```
 if x1(complex=true):
        x1 = nan

 if isinstance(x1, complex):
        x1 = nan

 x1[np.imag(x1) != 0] = nan

 x1[im(x1) != 0] = nan
```

I am getting error messages like this: `'Add' object does not support item assignment`
or `TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable` 
or `AttributeError: 'Add' object has no attribute 'imag'`

This is for emample a imaginary number:

```
5.62945452911547 - 82.1982564324793*I
```

Any ideas?

This is my script:

```
# Bibliotheken importieren
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pandas as pd
import formel_ShaoLu
from sympy import *
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

e = 10  # Anzahl Zeilen, die durchlaufen werden

print('Datei einlesen')
## Aus Datei lesen mit genfromtxt und ausgeben
data = np.genfromtxt(dateiname3, skip_header=1, usecols=(0,1,4), delimiter='\t', invalid_raise=False, filling_values=0)
print('Datei eingelesen')
xx = data[0:e,0]
yy = data[0:e,1]
velocity_1d = data[0:e,2]

# definiere Dataframe
vel_Coord = {'x':xx,
             'y':yy,
             'velocity': velocity_1d}       # in mm/s, muss im Modul umgerechnet werden!
df = pd.DataFrame(vel_Coord)
print('Dataframe wurde erzeugt')

# Geschwindigkeit in Durchmesser umrechnen
diameter1 = []
diameter2 = []
d, u1 = symbols('d, u1')
result = solve(formel_ShaoLu.u(d, u1), d)   # löst die Gleichung vorab
print(result)
for x in df.velocity:
    x1 = result[0].subs(u1,x).evalf()       # subs ersetzt u1 mit x
    x2 = result[1].subs(u1, x).evalf()      # evalf löst die Gleichung mit dem eingesetzten x
    x1 = x1/10**(-6)
    x2 = x2/10**(-6)
```

Here I want to check whether the value is imaginary or not and replace it with a nan

```
    # print(x1)
    # if x1.imag != 0:
    #     x1 = nan
    print('is it complex?')
    if x1(complex=true):
        x1 = nan
        print('It is complex')
    # x1[np.imag(x1) != 0] = nan
    # x2[x2.imag != 0] = nan
    diameter1.append(x1)                    # erstellt eine Liste von x1
    diameter2.append(x2)
df['diameter1'] = diameter1
df['diameter2'] = diameter2
print(df.diameter1)
print(df.diameter2)
```

And my modul with u(d, u1):

```
from sympy import *     

## Berechnung Geschwindigkeit u
def u(d, u1):
    return (A_N*(sigma_p(temp, roh_titan)*g*d+gamma/(roh_ar(temp)*d)))**(1/2)-u1*10**(-3)    # Geschwindigkeit wird von mm/s in m/s umgerechnet

## Berechnung Dichte Argon
def roh_ar(temp):
    return p*M_Ar/(R*temp)


## Berechnung Verhältnis der Dichte
def sigma_p(temp, roh_titan):
    return roh_titan/roh_ar(temp)
```

Comment: I can't run this code since you import a library google hasn't heard of. isinstance(x1,complex) is the right way to test for being complex, x1=nan works for me, but again, i'm not on your context, so...

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of a "how do I find out if a sympy number is complex" question; none of the later code is actually relevant.

Comment: @DSM thank you. i didn't found that question

Answer (score 0):

Can it be a format issue? When I type

```
import sympy
x1 = 5.62945452911547 - 82.1982564324793*I
```

In my IPython console, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-2caa666b2f5b>", line 1, in <module>
    x1 = 5.62945452911547 - 82.1982564324793*I

NameError: name 'I' is not defined
```

I can not test the whole code because I don't have all the packages installed on my computer. Can you decompose your result when you do `x1 = result[0].subs(u1,x).evalf()`?

However, `isinstance(x, complex)` is usually how to test if x1 is complex.

Comment: 1) The `I` being referenced is `sympy.I`.  2) If you build such an x1, you'll discover that `isinstance(x1, complex)` is actually False, because the sympy object isn't a subclass of the Python class `complex`.

Comment: I found out that `x1 = result[0].subs(u1,x).evalf()` is an Add and this is another format than numpy for example

Comment: @DMS Ok, thanks for these explanations. So I had a syntax error in my test _ _'